# how to add phone number in aws using python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

```
import boto3

# Create an SNS client
client = boto3.client(
    "sns",
    aws_access_key_id="YOUR ACCES KEY",
    aws_secret_access_key="YOUR SECRET KEY",
    region_name="us-east-1"
)

# Send your sms message.
client.publish(
    PhoneNumber ="+12223334444",
    Message="Hello World!"
)
```

i have already added my number in aws SNS console ,and only to that number i can send message
if i want to send message to any other number, how can i send the messages to other phone numbers using pyhton and how can i add phone number in aws console using python

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a little unclear. Are you saying that you can successfully receive a message that is sent to your phone number, but messages sent to different phones numbers fails? Are those (failing) phone numbers in the same country (USA)? If so, you can activate message logging, see: [Access Amazon SNS topic delivery logs for SMS messages](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/)

Comment: i have already added my number in aws sns console thats why only to that number messages are sending,

Comment: if i delete my number from aws sns account ,for that also message will not send

Comment: how to send messages to users using python code

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to send messages in Amazon SNS:

- Send directly to a phone number by using `client.publish(PhoneNumber="...")`, or
- Send a message to an Amazon SNS Topic, and the message will be sent to all Subscribers of that topic

Subscriptions can be via email, SMS, HTTP Endpoint, etc.

Your code is using the first method, so it is sending the message to a specific phone number. If you actually want to send the message to multiple recipients, then create an SNS Topic, subscribe the recipients and then send the message to the SNS Topic using: `client.publish(TopicArn="...")`